# How do you recover a Skype account by using a Microsoft account?

Tags: skype, password-recovery, microsoft-account

I created a Skype account using email way. Then I had linked to Microsoft account. Over time I forgot my password to Skype and lost access to primary email. Now I can sign into Skype only using my linked Microsoft account. I want to have access to Skype account by login and password Skype. How can I do it if I only have access into Microsoft account?

Comment: You can sign in to Skype using your Microsoft account... you only need to a Skype account if you have previously created a Skype account...???

Comment: To put it simply: **You don't**.  If you don't have the capability to reset the password to the Skype account because you don't have access to the email registered to the said Skype account and your current Microsoft Account is not been linked to said Skype account it won't be possible to gain access to that Skype account.

Comment: @Ramhound How exactly Microsoft account must been linked to Skype account? I can login to this Skype account using linked Microsoft account. I want change password or at least primary email at Skype account. Can I do that?

Comment: If you have not already linked the Skype account to the Microsoft Account it cannot be done.  It requires you know the username and password to the Skype account,  How you do it is documented on the Skype website, you basically just link the two accounts, after doing so it tells you that you should use the Microsoft Account in the future to log into the Skype account.  Are you sure you have not already done so, and are simply, trying to do something that does not need to be done?

Comment: @Ramhound  I can sign into Skype only using my linked Microsoft account. I want to have access to Skype account by login and password Skype. I don't have access to my primary Skype email to reset password. If I have access to Skype using my linked Microsoft account, can I change login and password of Skype account?

Comment: @Big Chris I created a Skype account using email way. Then I had linked to Microsoft account. Over time I forgot my password to Skype and lost access to primary email. Now I can sign into Skype only using my linked Microsoft account. Can I change login and password of Skype account?

Comment: @user3660090 - Have you at any point linked the Skype account you want to access to the Microsoft Account you are currently using?  Skype accounts were discontinued awhile ago.  So its likely you did merge these accounts, forgot you did, and are trying to access an account for no reason.  If you did merge the accounts the contact list was already combined.  There is no reason to access the Skype account, they are already linked, when you log into the Microsoft Account your accessing the Skype account at the sameitme they are not one in the samething.

Comment: [https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA109/i-ve-forgotten-my-username-or-password](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA109/i-ve-forgotten-my-username-or-password) KB article from support Skype will help you to recover or access your Skype account.